# problema con ETL de postgresql a sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, odbc

Hola tengo un problema con un ETL que trae data de un servidor sql postgres a un
Micrisoft sql-server me arroja los siguientes errores:

```
ERROR: ADO NET source has failed to acquire connection.
```

El segundo error es el siguiente:

```
ERROR: (IM002)(Microsoft)(ODBC Driver Manager) Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Esto me ocurre al implementar el .dtsx en el servidor sql-server y genero el job para que se ejecute de manera periódica, desde mi equipo funciona sin ningún problema.

ya instale el driver (ODBC) de conexión de postgres en el servidor y también agregue la conexión indicada pero el error sigue apareciendo.

Bueno de antemano muchas gracias a quien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: ¿Está bien la cadena de conexión?

Comment: @fredyfx si la cadena de conexión esta bien desde mi equipo funciona sin ningún problema y me asegure que fuera la misma en el servidor

Comment: _Data source name not found_ parece indicar que no logra resolver el nombre del servidor (de postgreSQL). ¿Has intentado hacer telnet u otra forma de establecer una conexión desde el servidor de SQL Server al de postgreSQL?

Comment: @jachguate voy a probar